# Boot partition type to use for a GPT partition table

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch, guid-partition-table

I am creating a new [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) Linux build for my home Raspberry Pi system. I want to create a separate boot partition for the same. I am using a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition table. While creating the new partition using `gdisk`, it prompted me to chose the partition type. I could see dedicated boot partition types for Apple, [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) and [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), but not for generic Linux.

```
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): L
0700 Microsoft basic data  0c01 Microsoft reserved    2700 Windows RE
4200 Windows LDM data      4201 Windows LDM metadata  7501 IBM GPFS
7f00 ChromeOS kernel       7f01 ChromeOS root         7f02 ChromeOS reserved
8200 Linux swap            8300 Linux filesystem      8301 Linux reserved
8e00 Linux LVM             a500 FreeBSD disklabel     a501 FreeBSD boot
a502 FreeBSD swap          a503 FreeBSD UFS           a504 FreeBSD ZFS
a505 FreeBSD Vinum/RAID    a580 Midnight BSD data     a581 Midnight BSD boot
a582 Midnight BSD swap     a583 Midnight BSD UFS      a584 Midnight BSD ZFS
a585 Midnight BSD Vinum    a800 Apple UFS             a901 NetBSD swap
a902 NetBSD FFS            a903 NetBSD LFS            a904 NetBSD concatenated
a905 NetBSD encrypted      a906 NetBSD RAID           ab00 Apple boot
af00 Apple HFS/HFS+        af01 Apple RAID            af02 Apple RAID offline
af03 Apple label           af04 AppleTV recovery      af05 Apple Core Storage
be00 Solaris boot          bf00 Solaris root          bf01 Solaris /usr & Mac Z
bf02 Solaris swap          bf03 Solaris backup        bf04 Solaris /var
bf05 Solaris /home         bf06 Solaris alternate se  bf07 Solaris Reserved 1
bf08 Solaris Reserved 2    bf09 Solaris Reserved 3    bf0a Solaris Reserved 4
bf0b Solaris Reserved 5    c001 HP-UX data            c002 HP-UX service
ef00 EFI System            ef01 MBR partition scheme  ef02 BIOS boot partition
fd00 Linux RAID
```

Which boot partition type should I choose to go for a custom Linux build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ef02 for your boot partition, and 8300 for your filesystem:

http://manual.aptosid.com/en/part-gdisk-en.htm

Comment: Note that this (ef02) is not for the normal Linux boot partition as it isn't even allowed to have a filesystem on it! It's only required if you want to use GPT on a BIOS system and you have to create an extra normal boot partition (or included in root) that has a filesystem on it then. More info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions
For normal Linux boot partition use 8300, for /boot as a directory in the root partition see here for types: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/

Answer (score 2):

You should use 8300 `Linux filesystem` for boot, as well as other (but not swap) purposes.